# Listen to background thread from UI JavaFX

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, javafx, javafx-2

I have one problem. I am creating JavaFX application for desktop. I have thread in my app that runs in background, let's assume that it is downloading files from the internet.
I have read articles about concurrency in JavaFX. There is special class Task. I have extended my class with Task. But it can only return some value and after that it will shut down.
But I need to have this task running during all app lifetime, and when , for instance file is downloaded, it should post result to the UI thread, to be more precise on controller which in turn update some ui component.
I know that Task has updateProgress method, maybe I can bind it not only to receive integers, but complex Objects.
Or there is other good approach to follow in my case.
Please help with this problem.

Comment: Any special reasons for making the *task run throughout the app lifetime* and not create it whenever required?

Comment: The answer to @ItachiUchiha's question depends on whether the file download (or whatever the background thread does) is requested from the UI (e.g. clicking the "download" button), in which case you could create the task on demand, or whether it is completely independent of UI actions.

Comment: No, downloadin files is just example, okey, I will be hones, mail checking service running through all app lifetime

Comment: [ScheduledService](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/concurrent/ScheduledService.html) suits your scenario. There are other methods of achieving it as well, for example, [TimerTask](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TimerTask.html).

Comment: Thx I will try, post you comment as answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JavaFX provides you with [ScheduledService](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/concurrent/ScheduledService.html) which can be scheduled for repetitive works. The javadoc says,

> The ScheduledService is a Service which will automatically restart
>   itself after a successful execution, and under some conditions will
>   restart even in case of failure.

A very simple example would be :

```
ScheduledService<Object> service = new ScheduledService<Object>() {
     protected Task<Object> createTask() {
         return new Task<Object>() {
             protected Object call() {
                 // Connect to a Server
                 // Download the object
                 updateProgress(...);
                 return object; // Useful in case you want to return data, else null
             }
         };
     }
 };
 service.setPeriod(Duration.seconds(10)); //Runs every 10 seconds
 //bind the service progress/message properties
 progressBar.progressProperty().bind(service.progressProperty());
```

There are non-javafx ways to achieve this as well, you can use :

- [ScheduledExecutorService](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html)
- [TimerTask](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TimerTask.html)

Comment: Works like a charm, by the way

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way here would be to use plain old Thread:

```
// create new thread at start, e.g. at the end for Application.start() method
new Thread(new Runnable() {
  public void run() {
      while(true) {
           //load my data 
           // once loaded
           // update UI using 
           Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
               public void run() {
                   // here goes my update on FX UI thread
               }
           });
           // update is done let's look for more data
      }
  }
}).start();
```